# SAPI 5 TTS Events

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm writing to ask you some advices for a particular problem regarding SAPI engine. I have an application that can speak both to the speakers and to a WAV file. I also need some events to be aware, i.e. word boundary and end input.

```
    m_cpVoice->SetNotifyWindowMessage(m_hWnd, TTS_MSG, 0, 0);
    hr = m_cpVoice->SetInterest(SPFEI_ALL_EVENTS, SPFEI_ALL_EVENTS);
```

Just for test I added all events! When the engine speaks to speakers all events are triggered and sent to the `m_hWnd` window, but when I set output to the WAV file, none of them are sent

```
    CSpStreamFormat fmt;  
    CComPtr<ISpStreamFormat> pOld;

    m_cpVoice->GetOutputStream(&pOld);
    fmt.AssignFormat(pOld);
    SPBindToFile(file, SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS, &m_wavStream, &fmt.FormatId(), fmt.WaveFormatExPtr());
    m_cpVoice->SetOutput(m_wavStream, false);
    m_cpVoice->Speak(L"Test", SPF_ASYNC, 0);
```

Where `file` is a path passed as argument.

Really this code is taken from the TTS samples found on the SAPI SDK. It seems a little bit obscure the part setting the format...

Can you help me in finding the problem? Or does anyone of you know a better way to write TTS to WAV? I can not use manager code, it should be better to use the C++ version...

Thank you very much for help

### EDIT 1

This seems to be a thread problem and searching in the `spuihelp.h` file, that contains the `SPBindToFile` helper I found that it uses the `CoCreateInstance()` function to create the stream. Maybe this is where the `ISpVoice` object looses its ability to send event in its creation thread.

What do you think about that?

Comment: Can't tell from the code posted, but when you send to the WAV file, are you pumping messages somewhere?

Comment: How are you compiling your code - Visual Studio? If so which version?

Comment: @EricBrown well... really not... I read about that, but the 'famous' WaitAndPumpMessage() function is still blocking (isn't it?)

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff yes, I'm using the community 2015!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adopted an on-the-fly solution that I think should be acceptable in most of the cases, In fact when you write speech on files, the major event you would be aware is the "stop" event.

So... take a look a the class definition:

```
    #define TTS_WAV_SAVED_MSG            5000
    #define TTS_WAV_ERROR_MSG            5001

    class CSpeech { 
    public:
        CSpeech(HWND); // needed for the notifications
        ...
    private:
        HWND m_hWnd;
        CComPtr<ISpVoice> m_cpVoice;
        ...
        std::thread* m_thread;

        void WriteToWave();
        void SpeakToWave(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR);
    };
```

I implemented the method `SpeakToWav` as follows

```
    // Global variables (***)
    LPCWSTR tMsg;
    LPCWSTR tFile;
    long tRate;
    HWND tHwnd;
    ISpObjectToken* pToken;

    void CSpeech::SpeakToWave(LPCWSTR file, LPCWSTR msg) {
        // Using, for example wcscpy_s:
        // tMsg <- msg;
        // tFile <- file;

        tHwnd = m_hWnd;
        m_cpVoice->GetRate(&tRate);
        m_cpVoice->GetVoice(&pToken);

        if(m_thread == NULL)
            m_thread = new std::thread(&CSpeech::WriteToWave, this);
    }
```

And now... take a look at the `WriteToWave()` method:

```
    void CSpeech::WriteToWav() {
        // create a new ISpVoice that exists only in this
        // new thread, so we need to 
        //
        // CoInitialize(...) and...
        // CoCreateInstance(...)

        // Now set the voice, i.e. 
        //    rate with global tRate, 
        //    voice token with global pToken
        //    output format and...
        //    bind the stream using tFile as I did in the 
        //      code listed in my question

        cpVoice->Speak(tMsg, SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, 0);
        ...
```

Now, because we did not used the `SPF_ASYNC` flag the call is blocking, but because we are on a separate thread the main thread can continue. After the `Speak()` method finished the new thread can continue as follow:

```
        ...
        if(/* Speak is went ok */)
            ::PostMessage(tHwn, TTS_WAV_SAVED_MSG, 0, 0);
        else
            ::PostMessage(tHwnd, TTS_WAV_ERROR_MSG, 0, 0);
    }
```

(***) OK! using global variables is not quite cool :) but I was going fast. Maybe using a thread with the `std::reference_wrapper` to pass parameters would be more elegant!

Obviously, when receiving the TTS messages you need to clean the thread for a next time call! This can be done using a `CSpeech::CleanThread()` method like this:

```
    void CSpeech::CleanThread() {
        m_thread->join(); // I prefer to be sure the thread has finished!
        delete m_thread;
        m_thread = NULL;
    }
```

What do you think about this solution? Too complex?